# Write as single interval $( -5 , 3 ] \cap [ 1 , 6 )$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I write $( -5 , 3 ] \cap [ 1 , 6 )$ as a single interval ? Please explain the steps if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Starlight that answered my question. (You should put it as an answer so I can give you credit) :)

Comment: Why the downvote..

Comment: Seriously, downvoters should explain why they are downvoting, especially for a new user. Personally, I think the downvotes are meanspirited and unnecessary.

Comment: @SimonS Totally agree!

Comment: I mean I am not professing to be a math genius. I am purely asking these questions so that I can do well on my college exam (CIS major)

Comment: @SimonS--agreed!

Comment: @MattButler  While I did not cast a downvote, your question would be better received if you gave some indication that you thought about the problem yourself.  For instance, you could indicate that you understood what the intervals mean, understood what intersection means, or showed an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I did not downvote but I would say that it is because you haven't really put down anything you've tried, thoughts on the problem or any reasons why you cannot do the problem by yourself.

Comment: I thought through the problem in my head, but I did not really know how to approach it. I thought it would be best just to learn the problem the correct way from the start. Sorry for the lack of info guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Starlight suggested in the comment section, drawing the intervals on a number line can help. Let $A=(-5,3]$ and $B=[1,6)$. The picture below then shows the segments that both $A$ and $B$ represent.

You wish to compute the intersection of $A$ and $B$ ($A\cap B$), or, simply put, what elements $A$ and $B$ have in common. This is seen in the overlap of the two segments (enclosed by the dotted lines). We find that this segment in interval notation is identical to $[1,3], $ which is the answer to your question.[image]

Comment: What a champ. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I feel the sarcasm @MattButler! lol you're welcome.

Comment: I did not intend for sarcasm. I do appreciate your effort to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since $( -5, 3] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -5 < x \leq 3 \}$ and $[1, 6) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 1 \leq x < 6 \}$, we have
$$
( -5, 3] \cap [1, 6) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 1 \leq x \leq 3 \} = [1, 3].
$$

Comment: You should try to use the same notation as the OP. (Which in this case is also the majority standard for 'open ends'.)

Comment: I consider it better to hint people that using $], [$ is better; for $(, )$ notation is used in lots of occasions. To develop such a habit is healthy in the long run.

Comment: Many authors (and leading mathematics journals) disagree with you. But more to the point: the OPer here might not know that notation at all and your use of it may not help them but possibly confuse and demotivate them.

Comment: The taste of leading math journals need not be the best.